# Graph with initializer_list<Edge> C++ - How I do to create Edges at initializer_list without "Edge" word?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

My Graph constructor:

```
Graph(std::initializer_list<Edge> list);
```

My Edge constructor:

```
Edge(int out, int in);
```

I wanna create my Graph by the following way:

```
Graph g = { (1,2), (3,4), (5,1), (5,3)};
```

but I just want a succeful compilation if I write:

```
Graph g = { Edge(1,2), Edge(3,4), Edge(5,1), Edge(5,3)};
```

How I do to create Edges at initializer_list without "Edge" word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `{}` to initialise each member; that will choose the two-argument constructor, assuming there is no constructor taking an `initializer_list`.

```
Graph g = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,1}, {5,3} };
```

However, I've found this doesn't work on some older compilers, in which case you might have to fall back to writing `Edge`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with parentheses, but with uniform initialization syntax (i.e. using braces) you can.

All you need is a constructor for `Edge` that accepts two integers (which you already have) and an `std::initializer_list<Edge>` as the only argument of `Graph`'s constructor (which you *almost* have, just missing the template argument):

```
#include <initializer_list> // FOR std::initializer_list

struct Edge
{
    Edge(int out, int in) { /* ... */ }

    // Do not put any constructor taking an std::initalizer_list here,
    // otherwise it will be picked instead of the one above when using
    // uniform initialization syntax.

    // ...
};

struct Graph
{
    Graph(std::initializer_list<Edge> list) { /* ... */ }

    // ...
};
```

Then, you can construct your graphs as follows:

```
int main()
{
    Graph g1 = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,1}, {5,3} };
    Graph g2 = { Edge(1,2), Edge(3,4), Edge(5,1), Edge(5,3) };
    Graph g3 = { Edge{1,2}, Edge{3,4}, Edge{5,1}, Edge{5,3} };
}
```

Here is a compiling [**live example**](http://ideone.com/EjoKlO).

Answer (score 0):

You're using parens instead of braces:

```
Graph g = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,1}, {5,3}};
```

This will actually call `Graph's` constructor taking an `std::initializer_list`.